# Network error on main thread, while using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I am trying to build my first android app, it uses AsyncTask to execute a post request.
(to log into a website).

I got the app working fine with StrictMode turned off, but i would like it to be error free when executed in StrictMode also. Eventhough I redesigned my app using AsyncTask it still gives me this error:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
```

From what I have read on the internet, using AsyncTask should have solved this. I don't want to use Java Threads because i want to learn to do it the correct way.

I build a new class to execute the task, it's called MyAsyncTask, here is de class code

```
<code>
package com.am.tuto;
import android.os.AsyncTask;// removed rest of imports for readability
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
String u;
String p;

public MyAsyncTask(String u, String p)
{
    this.u=u;
    this.p=p;
}

@Override protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
String msg="";
if ((u.length()>0)&&(p.length()>0))
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://irrationalgamers.com/test.php");
try 
{
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", u));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", p));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response =httpclient.execute(httppost); // <----the error occurs
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(responseString);
    msg="success";
    msg=responseString;
} 

catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}  
}
else
{
   msg="failed";
}
return msg;
}

@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    MyBus.getInstance().post(new AsyncTaskResultEvent(doInBackground()));
}
}
</code>
```

I am thinking that it might be because i created my own constructor, but i feel I really have to pass it some parameters.

I can continue programming the app, but it would be nice to learn how to prevent this issue in the future. Every article i read on the error points me to AsyncTask, it's hard to find a solution for when already implemented...

Any thoughts on this would be highly aprreciated

Comment: how you are starting `AsyncTask`?

Comment: how do you run the AsyncTask? With get or execute?

Comment: @blackbelt I am running it with execute

Comment: Format your code with some indentation. To your question, simply using AsyncTask doesn't solve the problem. Every method **except** `doInBackground()` runs on the UI so make sure you aren't doing any network stuff in any of the other methods.

Comment: @codemagic i think i'm doing all network related stuffin this method..... unless you see something I don't :)

Comment: `MyBus.getInstance().post(new AsyncTaskResultEvent(doInBackground()));` line causing issue in `onPostExecute` because `onPostExecute` always run on UI Thread and you are calling `doInBackground` from `onPostExecute`

Comment: I'm not even looking to see until there is some indentation but probably what @ρяσѕρєяK said

Comment: Thank you, i will try to see if i can move it around, and i'll let you know if it works

Comment: @codemagic i'll try what he said , and i made some indentation anyway :)

Comment: It just throws me a new exception, it think the bus has to be run off of the main-thread.... 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Event bus [Bus "default"] accessed from non-main thread null

Comment: @BartHofma : what happen when you are running app without `MyBus.getInstance().post(new AsyncTaskResultEvent(doInBackground()));` line ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K then it works fine, also when i comment the network stuff, i think it is becoming clear to me. Thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, ρяσѕρєя K answered your question. Some extra details: you should never call `doInBackground` yourself. The whole point of `AsyncTask` is that it manages passing the work to the background worker thread and returning the results to the UI thread. What `doInBackground` returns is what `onPostExecute` receives as a parameter.

Your `onPostExecute` should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    MyBus.getInstance().post(new AsyncTaskResultEvent(result));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input, I can't test my code over the weekend but i think my question is answered. Though I still don't understand when the doInBackground() method is being called, I'll accept the answer as it answers the question i put up :) Does it run on object creation?

Comment: ```AsyncTask``` will do that for you, you don't have to call it explicitly. So, what you do is enough: ```new MyAsyncTask(username, password).execute()```

Comment: & ρяσѕρєя K Thank you for explaining it this well, instead of just copy/pasting a solution, I know where I made the mistake, and where to look if it happens again. I'll try out the code when i get home after the weekend :D

Comment: i just tried doing it like this and I just wanted to let you know it worked perfectly! Thanks again :)